# Regex: Check if (among others) specific characters are present in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with next.js and I have a string (url).
I need to check if the string contains at least 3x "/". Other chars are also present (letters, numbers and "-") - but they don't need to match something specific.

**Example:**

- "/apple/green-sour/south-spain" or "/red-orange/sweet/north-italy-toscany" -> check, if 3x "/" are present -> YES
- "/kiwi/new-zealan" -> check, if 3x "/" are present -> NO

I think I need the following snippets:

- [A-Za-Z0-9] -> numbers and chars
- [-] -> slash
- [/]{3} -> 3x "/"

I just don't know how to put them together in a regex. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A very specific pattern for you could be `^(?:\/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*){3,}$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeat the `/` followed by the accepted characters 3 or more times.

Note that `[A-Za-Z0-9]` should be `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead.

```
^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9-]+){3,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2XVm9E/1)

To not match `-` only, or at the start or end, you can optionally repeat it:

```
^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*){3,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOFkYf/1)

Comment: `^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*){3,}` is functionally equivalent to that second example and less complex. +1

Comment: @AD7six It is almost the same :-) only it will allow for consecutive `----` like https://regex101.com/r/xxPksz/1 but if the OP is ok with that is is a less complex solution indeed.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I had some struggles to integrate the regex in my code but now everything works :) One tiny thing that I've changed: I used {3}, instead of {3,}. This is because I need exactly 3 occurrences of "/" and not 3 or more. Your demo was very helpful :)